# Format for distributing my CA certificate

Tags: ssl, ca

I have generated my own CA files - cacert.pem, careq.pem, cakey.pem.

The internet explained that I definitely shouldn't use PKCS#12 (.p12) as it exposes my private key and that browsers like .der format (which is binary format for pem?!). This just enhances the confusion.

From my point of understanding this http://www.cacert.org/certs/root.txt is a .pem, right? And if I cut everything out, except the "PEM armor" I get a .crt?

So the question is: how do I safely (!) distribute this root certificate for installations on client workstations (.pem, .crt, etc)?

Comment: The very basic format is DER (which is a form of ASN.1). PEM is basically a base64-encoded DER with header and footer lines added. Windows software prefers DER, on linux OpenSSL normally uses PEM format. You choose.

Comment: You should made this as an answer. Thanks! :)